# Android TextView defStyle parameter ignored?

Tags: c#, android, mono, textview, xamarin.android

**Note that I am using Mono for Android**

I have a ListView of items that can be extended by clicking a "More" button at the bottom of the list. The list is defined in XML but the more button is simply a clickable TextView that is added to the bottom of the list via AddFooterView. I am trying to apply a pre-defined style to the runtime-created TextView but it is not working.

```
mMoreProductsButton = new TextView(this, null, Resource.Style.more_button);
mMoreProductsButton.Text = "More";
mMoreProductsButton.Click += new EventHandler(MoreProductsButton_Click);
mListView.AddFooterView(mMoreProductsButton);
```

TextView documentation shows this signature: `TextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)`

`defStyle` is defined in the documentation as the default style to apply to the view. An example I saw elsewhere passed null as the AttributeSet but I'm not sure if that is valid or related to my problem.

I found this bug and am not sure if it is related and current:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12683

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I also searched answer to this question. It seems to be an Android bug because I didn't found a way of style applying to creating Views.
Why don't you want to inflate your TextView?
Like this:

**layout/my_view.xml**

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:style="@style/more_button" />
```

**Activity**

```
TextView mMoreProductsButton = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_view, null, false);
```

Sorry, I don't know if it workable in Mono.

Comment: That's workable in Mono and I do that in lots of other places where I'm assembling complex layouts. In this case it seemed wasteful to create an XML resource and then load and inflate it when it's just a simple TextView. It's strange to me that the Android platform wouldn't support the dynamic creation of styled elements.