# MonoDroid bugs with ListView.ItemClick and AddFooterView

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.android

I have discovered a few issues with ListViews in Mono for Android that may be bugs. I have posted a fairly-simple project that demos both of these issues in more detail here:
[Example Project](http://yolabs.com/stuff/MonoListBugs.zip)

I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong or if these are legitimate bugs.

---

**First**, if you try to use an inflated view as the footer view for a ListView by calling AddFooterView it throws a ClassCastException. Using a dynamically-created view works fine but you [can't apply styles to a dynamically created view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772472/android-textview-defstyle-parameter-ignored).
So this works fine:

```
goodButton.Click += delegate {
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.Text = "THIS IS THE LIST FOOTER";
    listView.AddFooterView(tv);
    listView.Adapter = adapter;
    Toast.MakeText(this, "Footer was added...", ToastLength.Short).Show();
};
```

But this throws ClassCastException:

```
TextView footerViewButton = FindViewById(Resource.Id.listFooterButton) as TextView;
badButton.Click += delegate {
    listView.AddFooterView(footerViewButton);
    listView.Adapter = adapter;
    Toast.MakeText(this, "Custom Footer was moved...", ToastLength.Short).Show();
};
```

---

**Second**, if you create a ListView and set an ItemClick handle, then call NotifyDataSetChanged() on the ListView the ItemClick event is no longer fired:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ItemClick);
    ListView list = FindViewById(Resource.Id.itemClickList) as ListView;
    mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, Countries);
    list.Adapter = mAdapter;
    list.ItemClick += new EventHandler<ItemEventArgs>(list_ItemClick);
}
```

The CustomAdapter calls this method in the activity when the last view in the list is rendered:

```
public void GetMoreListItems() {
    if (mAdapter.Count < Countries.Length + MoreCountries.Length) {
        string[] allCountries = new string[Countries.Length + MoreCountries.Length];
        Countries.CopyTo(allCountries, 0);
        MoreCountries.CopyTo(allCountries, Countries.Length);
        mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged(allCountries);
        Toast.MakeText(this, "New items were loaded. Now Click action is broken.", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering if I'm doing something against pattern here or if these are legitimate bugs. I updated my post to clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) issue is not a bug. If you want to use styles for you footer view you can create xml layout for it and then use `LayoutInflater` to instantiate it and add as footer view to your list.

```
var footerView = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.footerView,null);
listView.AddFooterView(footerView);
```

2) I also had problem with it and i have spent some time trying to find the problem. After all i decided to ignore it and use `NotifyDataSetChanged()` method without parameters. And to update the adapter i have created method something like `.SetItems(IEnumerable<TItem> items)`. So my code looks like this:

```
var newItems=Service.LoadNewItems();
adapter.SetItems(newItems);
adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
```

And all works fine for me. ListItemClick delegate is invoking.

Comment: I confirmed that I was just doing things incorrectly on issue 1. For some reason I thought that a Layout resource had to have a Layout type (Linear/RelativeLayout etc) as a root element and so I was doing something pretty convoluted to work around that.

Comment: On Issue 2 I can't get your fix to work. I changed my CustomAdapter in the sample project so that it has an `UpdateStrings(string[] newStrings)` method and completely removed the customized  `NotifyDataSetChanged()` method. The behavior is exactly the same (no delegate invoked). There's probably something else I'm doing wrong. Here is the example project above, updated with your suggested changes: http://yolabs.com/stuff/MonoListBugs2.zip

Comment: I have looked at you code and have done some fixes so now it is working well. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15846138/MonoTests.zip

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. This works great. I originally had an OnScroll method similar to yours but it was getting called constantly and I couldn't figure out what was wrong. Seeing this makes everything a lot more clear. Thanks again.